Wave design on a div border
I'm trying to clone some projects interfaces on dribble for study purposes and raise my css skills, i've selected the layout below:

As you can see it's a mobile interface but i'm using react dom to build it ( as i mention before, it's just for study purpose ).
My problem is about this wavy bordered div's on the top and the bottom of the layout, i have tried to follow some tutorials but i did not be able to do it.
What i've tried:
At first i have tried css to solve this, using position absulote an z-index to render divs to "hide" the purple background, but the final result was weird. Here is my code:
import { Flex, useBreakpointValue } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { Box, Flex } from '@chakra-ui/react';


const Curve = () => (
    <Box
        position="absolute"
        height="33vh"
        width="100%"
        bottom="0"
        textAlign="center"
    >
        <Box
            content='""'
            display="block"
            position="absolute"
            borderRadius="100% 28%"
            width="69.5%"
            height="33vh"
            transform="translate(85%, 60%)"
            backgroundColor="#f8f9fc"
            top={5}
            left={-20}
        />
        <Box
            content='""'
            display="block"
            position="absolute"
            borderRadius="100% 45%"
            width="75%"
            height="33vh"
            backgroundColor="#3B3486"
            transform="translate(-4%, 40%)"
            zIndex="1"
            top={5}
            left={-20}
        />
    </Box>
);

export function Login() {
    return (
        <>
            <Box background="#3B3486" position="relative">
                <Flex pt="9rem" />
                <Curve />
            </Box>
            <Flex
                h={'70vh'}
                flex={1}
                justifyContent={'center'}
                alignItems={'center'}
            >
                Content
            </Flex>
        </>
    );
}

At last, i read that i can use SVG elements to handle it, but the final result was not responsive to other layouts. I would like to use css to solve it because it is the purpose of this clone. Is it possible to do it?

Aclip-path: path would have no trouble being responsive

I never reached at this prop before, it looks like css trying to draw an svg on screen, is it? i'm going to try this. Thank you!

adsy's answer already show you the steps to use clip-path, so here's my attempt to recreate the path. (Click the "Full page" button and resize your windows to test responsiveness)


:root {
  --bg: #3B3486;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

body::before,
body::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 33.33%;
  background-color: var(--bg);
  clip-path: url(#wavy-clip-path);
  z-index: -1;
}

body::after {
  top: unset;
  bottom: 0;
  scale: -1;
}
<svg class="svg">
  <clipPath id="wavy-clip-path" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <path d="M0,0 l1,0 c0,0.25 -0.15,0.33 -0.5,0.5 -0.33,0.15 -0.5,0.25 -0.5,0.5 z"></path>
  </clipPath>
</svg>



Alternatively, if you want pure CSS without SVG, you can try border-radius (the curve won't be exactly like your example though)


:root {
  --bg: #3B3486;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 33.33% 33.33% 33.33%;
}

header,
footer,
main {
  position: relative;
}

header::before,
footer::before,
main::before,
header::after,
footer::after,
main::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: var(--bg);
  z-index: -1;
}

header::before {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 100%;
}

header::after {
  top: unset;
  bottom: 0;
}

footer::before {
  border-top-left-radius: 50% 100%;
  top: unset;
  bottom: 0;
}

footer::after {
  z-index: -2;
}

main::before {
  border-top-left-radius: 50% 100%;
  top: unset;
  bottom: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

main::after {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 100%;
  top: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
<header></header>
<main></main>
<footer></footer>




It works perfectly in responsivity. Did you use some other tool to build de svg properties?
Looks like you build a entire solution using clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" above. Awesome!

Man, where you build this svg path, did you used some tool? That's the best suitable path for this layout. Can you teach me how you reached at this solution?

I think adsy's answer explained this method way better than mine, all I did was adjusting the path. The clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" was to make the path stretch itself to elements it's applied to instead of using its own size. I have some experience with vector graphics, so I can type some simple path directly. With more complex paths, I usually use vectorpea.com to draw and export to SVG file, then notepad (or any text editor) to open the file and copy the paths data.

The clip-path CSS property can do what you want. However, arriving at a path that matches your shape and is responsive has some steps.
First, we can create the path we will use using an SVG editor. For example I have created an approximate curve using this tool. This gives me the SVG path:
m429 0c-46 97-392 39-430 129l430 0V0

Unfortunately, using this like clip-path: path("m429 0c-46 97-392 39-430 129l430 0V0"); won't yield what you want since it won't be responsive. The path needs to be treated as relative to the container for that to happen and by default, this will not do that.
One approach is to insert a dummy SVG into the page containing a <clipPath clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"> and a child <path> with those points above, and then reference this using clip-path: url(#your-clippath-id). This is detailed in this answer.
However, this is a little cumbersome as you need to have additional SVG elements if only to reference them from the CSS. Another approach that avoids this is to convert the path to a polygon (which uses percentages) using some separate tool. I used this answer to successfully derive a polygon, which can be used with clip-path directly. This gave me:
clip-path: polygon(99.77% 0.00%, 98.58% 6.65%, 97.06% 12.50%, 95.29% 17.54%, 93.36% 21.86%, 91.32% 25.56%, 89.20% 28.75%, 87.03% 31.52%, 84.82% 33.95%, 82.58% 36.08%, 80.33% 37.97%, 78.06% 39.66%, 75.78% 41.17%, 73.49% 42.53%, 71.19% 43.77%, 68.89% 44.90%, 66.59% 45.93%, 64.28% 46.89%, 61.97% 47.79%, 59.66% 48.63%, 57.34% 49.42%, 55.03% 50.18%, 52.72% 50.91%, 50.40% 51.63%, 48.08% 52.34%, 45.77% 53.04%, 43.45% 53.76%, 41.14% 54.49%, 38.82% 55.24%, 36.51% 56.03%, 34.20% 56.87%, 31.89% 57.76%, 29.58% 58.72%, 27.27% 59.76%, 24.97% 60.90%, 22.68% 62.17%, 20.39% 63.57%, 18.12% 65.14%, 15.85% 66.92%, 13.61% 68.95%, 11.39% 71.28%, 9.21% 73.98%, 7.09% 77.15%, 5.06% 80.91%, 3.16% 85.41%, 1.50% 90.80%, 0.18% 97.16%, 1.15% 100.00%, 3.47% 100.00%, 5.80% 100.00%, 8.13% 100.00%, 10.45% 100.00%, 12.78% 100.00%, 15.10% 100.00%, 17.43% 100.00%, 19.75% 100.00%, 22.08% 100.00%, 24.40% 100.00%, 26.73% 100.00%, 29.06% 100.00%, 31.38% 100.00%, 33.71% 100.00%, 36.03% 100.00%, 38.36% 100.00%, 40.68% 100.00%, 43.01% 100.00%, 45.33% 100.00%, 47.66% 100.00%, 49.99% 100.00%, 52.31% 100.00%, 54.64% 100.00%, 56.96% 100.00%, 59.29% 100.00%, 61.61% 100.00%, 63.94% 100.00%, 66.26% 100.00%, 68.59% 100.00%, 70.92% 100.00%, 73.24% 100.00%, 75.57% 100.00%, 77.89% 100.00%, 80.22% 100.00%, 82.54% 100.00%, 84.87% 100.00%, 87.20% 100.00%, 89.52% 100.00%, 91.85% 100.00%, 94.17% 100.00%, 96.50% 100.00%, 98.82% 100.00%, 99.77% 95.40%, 99.77% 87.64%, 99.77% 79.89%, 99.77% 72.14%, 99.77% 64.39%, 99.77% 56.64%, 99.77% 48.88%, 99.77% 41.13%, 99.77% 33.38%, 99.77% 25.63%, 99.77% 17.88%, 99.77% 10.12%);


Edit: I needed to clean this up a bit and remove some useless points as I think this generative code is imperfect and could be improved. This gives me:
clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 98.58% 6.65%, 97.06% 12.5%, 95.29% 17.54%, 93.36% 21.86%, 91.32% 25.56%, 89.2% 28.75%, 87.03% 31.52%, 84.82% 33.95%, 82.58% 36.08%, 80.33% 37.97%, 78.06% 39.66%, 75.78% 41.17%, 73.49% 42.53%, 71.19% 43.77%, 68.89% 44.9%, 66.59% 45.93%, 64.28% 46.89%, 61.97% 47.79%, 59.66% 48.63%, 57.34% 49.42%, 55.03% 50.18%, 52.72% 50.91%, 50.4% 51.63%, 48.08% 52.34%, 45.77% 53.04%, 43.45% 53.76%, 41.14% 54.49%, 38.82% 55.24%, 36.51% 56.03%, 34.2% 56.87%, 31.89% 57.76%, 29.58% 58.72%, 27.27% 59.76%, 24.97% 60.9%, 22.68% 62.17%, 20.39% 63.57%, 18.12% 65.14%, 15.85% 66.92%, 13.61% 68.95%, 11.39% 71.28%, 9.21% 73.98%, 7.09% 77.15%, 5.06% 80.91%, 3.16% 85.41%, 1.5% 90.8%, 0.18% 97.16%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);

This is big, but the less points there are, the more inaccurate the shape. The number of points is inversely proportional to the steps variable in the above answer.
You can then use this directly with a single <Box> component. The curve will scale with the width/height of that box.
For the one at the top of the page, you can use the same setup but with transform: scale(-1); applied to reflect it so it's the right way up.
Here is a visual demo of the result:


body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.clipped {
  margin:20px 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: purple;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 98.58% 6.65%, 97.06% 12.5%, 95.29% 17.54%, 93.36% 21.86%, 91.32% 25.56%, 89.2% 28.75%, 87.03% 31.52%, 84.82% 33.95%, 82.58% 36.08%, 80.33% 37.97%, 78.06% 39.66%, 75.78% 41.17%, 73.49% 42.53%, 71.19% 43.77%, 68.89% 44.9%, 66.59% 45.93%, 64.28% 46.89%, 61.97% 47.79%, 59.66% 48.63%, 57.34% 49.42%, 55.03% 50.18%, 52.72% 50.91%, 50.4% 51.63%, 48.08% 52.34%, 45.77% 53.04%, 43.45% 53.76%, 41.14% 54.49%, 38.82% 55.24%, 36.51% 56.03%, 34.2% 56.87%, 31.89% 57.76%, 29.58% 58.72%, 27.27% 59.76%, 24.97% 60.9%, 22.68% 62.17%, 20.39% 63.57%, 18.12% 65.14%, 15.85% 66.92%, 13.61% 68.95%, 11.39% 71.28%, 9.21% 73.98%, 7.09% 77.15%, 5.06% 80.91%, 3.16% 85.41%, 1.5% 90.8%, 0.18% 97.16%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
}

.inverted {
   transform: scale(-1);
}
<strong>Top:</strong>

<div class="clipped inverted"></div>

<strong>Bottom:</strong>
<div class="clipped"></div>




Im aware theres some weird clipping on this in the corners -- I'm just trying to find where it came from right now...

Now corrected. The answer I used to generate the polygons is imperfect and so I manually cleaned up some fo the points.

It works on my template, thanks a lot. I'll keep all this online tools for another oportunities.
Just for curiosity, you make some manually work on this polygons, is there any logical information on this polygon that i need to know to implement other features?
I'm going to try the  strategy as well just for a challenge too, looks like that the "SVG to Clip path converter" do not works perfectly sometimes.

The generator I used basically doesnt seem to be intelligent enough to detect corners and know it needs to put a point in the output polygon there. It probably could be fixed, but there's probably also other tools that do this (figma maybe? something like that). The other problem is that it generates many points for flat lines that really only need 2. I used https://unused-css.com/tools/clip-path-generator to clean up the points on the output polygon.

This way is cool in that you don't need any SVG elements, but the SVG way does allow you to express the path using SVG primitives which are more powerful and may be more accurate as a level of info is lost during the conversion to a polygon (though wether you can tell visually depends on the shape complexity).

It will be possible in future to do it with pure CSS and not have to mess around with polygons with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/basic-shape/shape.  However this is super new and not in mainline browsers yet.

Ok, your explanation saved me a lot! Thak you so much. I'm going to take some more layouts like that to pratice. I can use it in everything i wonder that should be "painted in the layout".
Last question: Can i have any performance issues using this approach? Or did i have to use it wisely for some other reasons?

Highly doubtful performance will be a factor. I would expect good performance across the board -- but if worried, can always test on an old mobile device or something.
